# Как скрыть текст, введенный пользователем?

Tags: jquery, javascript, плагин

Подскажите, есть вот такая вещь: пользователь вводит сообщение, но он может ввести сообщение длинной больше 1500 символов и тд. Как можно скрыть этот текст или заменить кнопкой, при нажатии на которую текст покажется весь? Есть ли какой нить плагин `jquery` для этого?! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может быть [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/KdfDz/) подойдёт?

Comment: Вы как всегда правы!Я как понимаю можно это же сделать не для diva но и для span ?Пс а можно потом же кнопку свернуть сделать ?

Comment: Конечно можно. Например, [таким макаром](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/KdfDz/4/)

Comment: А это же подойдет если текст не в диве а в span ?А почему не работает в 1.8 ?

Comment: Да, восьмая версия ведёт себя не привычно для нас. У меня не дошли руки досконально изучить все изменения. Пару дней назад пробежался мельком по [обзору изменений](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/), но уже стало ясно, что это переходная версия, в которой дают нам время на адаптацию. В версии 1.9 планируется убрать приличное количество методов, но уже в восьмой, некоторые или не работают, или работают не так, как мы привыкли.----------В общем, в [этом примере][2], я сделал вам в span-ах и адаптировал под версию 1.8

Answer (score 1):

А куда Вы вводите текст? В `input`, `textarea`, `div` c `contenteditable`?
Можно менять высоту блока при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: текст находиться в span